# How to use Google Caja HTML/CSS sanitizer JS library in Java

Tags: java, javascript, css, sanitization, google-caja

I have a Java API that accepts a custom CSS field. I need to sanitize the CSS before storing it in my database and would like to use [Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) for this.

First, I tried running the [Google Caja HTML/CSS sanitizer](http://caja.appspot.com/html-css-sanitizer-minified.js) JavaScript library using the [Rhino JavaScript engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino). Unfortunately, that didn't work because that library depends heavily on the existence of a DOM (specifically, the `window` object).

Next, I imported the Caja project from the [Maven repository](http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/maven/caja/caja/). I looked through some of the tests, but could not find an example of how to use the sanitizer.

I could try [bringing the browser to the server](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/), but that seems a bit excessive.

Has anyone been able to use Caja to sanitize a CSS string in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Caja works by intercepting program actions at runtime, not by rewriting.  What is your exact problem?  Do you want to prevent XSS, or do you want to prevent the CSS from changing your site's style? Are the css used as an attribute or in `<style>` element? Reference: https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Comment: My intention is to store user-defined CSS as a string in a database, and subsequently wrap that CSS string in `<style>` tags on another site. I'm not looking to use the bulk of the Caja library; only the HTML/CSS sanitizer.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows the sanitizer in action on a simple client application; I want to perform the same sort of sanitization in my Java API. http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/e4pzdLuf/

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to sanitise on a Java server, I would recommend using [OWASP HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project), which is apparently based on code from Caja.  It includes the ability to sanitise `<a>` elements to include `rel="nofollow"`.

```java
import org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory;
import static org.owasp.html.Sanitizers.BLOCKS;
import static org.owasp.html.Sanitizers.FORMATTING;
import static org.owasp.html.Sanitizers.IMAGES;
import static org.owasp.html.Sanitizers.LINKS;

PolicyFactory sanitiser = BLOCKS.and(FORMATTING).and(IMAGES).and(LINKS);
String htmlSanitised = sanitiser.sanitize(htmlSource)
```

Nevertheless, to invoke Caja from Java, this works both with Rhino (Java 7) and Nashorn (Java 8):

```java
import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CajaSanitiser {

    private final ScriptEngine engine;
    private final Bindings bindings;

    public CajaSanitiser() throws IOException, ScriptException {
        this.engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
        this.bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        String scriptName = "com/google/caja/plugin/html-css-sanitizer-minified.js";
        try (BufferedReader reader = getReader(scriptName)) {
            engine.eval(reader);
        }
        String identity = "function identity(value) {return value;}";
        engine.eval(identity);
    }

    private BufferedReader getReader(String name) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)));
    }

    public String sanitise(String htmlSource) throws ScriptException {
        bindings.put("src", htmlSource);
        // You can use other functions beside 'identity' if you
        // want to transform the html.
        // See https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer
        return (String) engine.eval("html_sanitize(src, identity, identity)");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CajaSanitiser sanitiser = new CajaSanitiser();
        String source = "<html>\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "<style>\n" +
                "h1 {color:blue;}\n" +
                "</style>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<h1>A heading</h1>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";
        System.out.println("Original HTML with CSS:");
        System.out.println(source);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Sanitised HTML:");
        System.out.println(sanitiser.sanitise(source));
    }
}
```

I used this as part of my Maven configuration:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>caja</groupId>
        <artifactId>caja</artifactId>
        <version>r5127</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>caja</id>
        <name>caja</name>
        <url>http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @seanf! I have not had a chance to test this solution yet, but will accept or follow up as soon as I do.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) is also a "Java project" and therefore you can execute anything Caja can do directly in java.
For example, you can take a look to a Caja unit test case to validate the CSS directly in java [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/caja/plugin/CssParserTest.java).

Comment: Hey Pau, thanks for your response. I'm aware that Caja is a Java project, but the unit test you link to is a far cry from a usable solution. I'm attempting to actually run the Caja HTML/CSS sanitizer script in Java to sanitize a CSS string. This example shows how to run a JavaScript unit test from an HTML file, which most likely does not depend on the presence of a DOM.

Comment: Also, these tests use `com.google.caja.util.RhinoTestBed` to run JavaScript unit tests without passing data to those script functions or handling a response object.